# Disable OpenGL for compiz from command line

Tags: command-line, compiz, opengl

I can run CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) and uncheck OpenGL.

How can I do the same thing, but from the command line? I need to add this step to a machine provisioning script.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=list --list-type=string /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins "[core,composite,decor,imgpng,compiztoolbox,regex,mousepoll,place,session,move]"
```

Answer (score 0):

still wonder what exactly the name of that openGL plugin is...

while one can revert to the default settings (which should commonly work):

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz
compiz --replace
```